# ¿Cómo puedo crear nuevas hojas de calculo con capitalize()?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un programa con Python para una tarea de automatización con Google Sheets y me gustaría crear nuevas filas pero que el nombre de la hoja sea la primera letra en Mayúscula, ya apliqué el método `capitalize()` pero no me quiere funcionar, continua los nombres en minúscula.

Comparto algo de código donde estoy aplicando el método `capitalize()`

Código:

```python
 # Convertir el nombre de la hoja ingresado por el usuario la primera en mayúscula
    nombre_hoja = nombre_hoja.capitalize()

    # Obtener todas las hojas existentes la primera en mayúscula
    existing_sheets = [sheet.title.capitalize() for sheet in spreadsheet.worksheets()]

    # Buscar la hoja con el nombre la primera en mayúscula
    if nombre_hoja.capitalize() in existing_sheets:
        # Si se encuentra la hoja, devuelve el nombre en su forma original
        return existing_sheets[existing_sheets.index(nombre_hoja)]

    # Si no se encuentra una coincidencia exacta, devuelve None
    return None

# Función para registrar un gasto
def registrar_gasto(spreadsheet, descripcion, categoria, valor, observaciones, nombre_hoja):
    if not spreadsheet:
        print("No se pudo conectar a Google Sheets. Verifica tus credenciales y conexión a Internet.")
        return
```